# How to use buggy service in Changi airport (Singapore)?

Tags: airports, singapore

How does one go about using buggy services in the Changi airport ?

I have never used one but would have thought it's as simple as waving one down and hitching a ride. However, recently when assisting someone I witnessed seniors, with visible difficulty in walking, being denied a buggy ride (repeatedly) from one gate to the other (considerable distance) as they were told the buggy rides are only for business class travellers! I want to be prepared in case I am transiting through Changi and need a buggy ride - I can't see myself travelling business class.

Comment: Have you asked your airline about wheelchair assistance?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Uhmm, I didn't need one. But the people I was assisting, although were able to walk, were clearly overwhelmed by the distance they'd have to walk.

Comment: The last few times she came to visit me my mother could walk short distances, but not the distances typical of large airports. Each time, she requested a wheelchair "for distance" and the airline arranged one. I believe the service was free, but she always tipped the attendant. That is probably what the people you were assisting should have done.

Answer (score 12):

The assisted services at Changi are a paid for service, not a complimentary service.

Anyone can prebook the buggy service through the [SATS](https://www.satsaffinity.com/singaporeair/Home.aspx) website, with prices starting around SGD90. They offer different options for arriving, departing and transit passengers.

Comment: That's a pretty elaborate service! It does not however offer just getting the buggy ride from gate A to gate B. I would have thought the world's best airport(2015) would be senior/injured flyer friendly (at least for travellers transiting while flying on SG Airlines. I was under the impression their high fares would include such airport services). Personally, I wouldn't spend a 100 bucks for a 5 minute buggy ride.

Comment: Singapore Air offers wheelchair and elderly assistance programs that you can arrange in advance to be added to your booking.  But that service is different than the buggy service.